# Why I don't see the namespace related to running docker container

Tags: linux, docker, linux-namespaces

I know I can use `nsenter` to execute host machine program, e.g. `netstat`, inside the running docker container like this:

```
sudo nsenter -t namespace_id -n netstat -putan
```

but for that I first need to figure out that namespace id.

I'm supposed to be able to do it like this:

```
# get container top level process id
$ docker inspect -f '{{.State.Pid}}' container_id

# use it to find the namespace id
$ lsns -t container_top_level_process_id
```

but when I do that `lsns -t ...` gives me empty output. What could be the reason for that? Is it possible that running the container through `docker copmose` somehow affects this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> but for that I first need to figure out that namespace id.

No you don't; using the `-t` argument to `nsenter you only need the PID of a process in the namespace. From the` nsenter` man page:

```
`-t`, `--target` *PID*
     Specify a target process to get contexts from. The paths to the contexts specified by pid are:
```

So once you have the main process pid:

```
pid=$(docker inspect -f '{{.State.Pid}}' container_id)
```

You can use that directly with `nsenter`:

```
nsenter -t $pid -n netstat -tln
```

Comment: thanks! I got confused indeed when reading [this article](https://www.redhat.com/sysadmin/container-namespaces-nsenter). I thought they were using `namespace_id` with `nsenter`, whereas they simply showed how to use `lsns` with a process id unrelated to `nsenter`. So I've tried to `nsenter` with process_id, and got this error `nsenter: cannot open /proc/119595/ns/net: No such file or directory`, I'm running as root. Any idea?

Comment: I'm not sure what's going on there; what you're doing -- using `nsenter` to enter the network namespace of running Docker containers -- works just fine on my system, using exactly the commands shown here. When you get that error, what is the output of `ps -f -p <pid>`?

Comment: @MaxKoretskyi Are you sure you're using the PID _as seen from the host process namespace_, as opposed to as viewed from within the container?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, yes, I'm doing it from the same terminal where I run `docker ps` to get the id of the running container. I'm using WSL2 on Win11, maybe that's the issue? But I doubut it

Comment: @larsks, when I run `ps -f -p <pid>`, I get nothing, just column headers `UID          PID    PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD`, could it be because I use docker compose to start the containers?

Comment: docker compose is not the issue (it's really just a fancy wrapper around `docker run`), but if you don't see the pid in the process list, that suggests that the container has exited. Do the containers still show up in `docker ps`? In general, when you use `docker inspect` to get a container pid, does that actually match the entry in the proces stable you see when using `ps`?

Comment: this is really weird, when I run `ps aux` as a root user, there's no process id that I get in the table at all. In fact, the last process has the id of `10163`, while the process id for the container that I get is `119595`, which is way too big.

Comment: If you're running docker desktop on Windows, you Docker environment is running **inside a Linux virtual machine**. The PID you see is only visible inside the VM, not in  your WSL environment.

Comment: @larsks, thanks! so what you're saying is that the `docker` command I use in WSL can come from Docker Desktop installation, not docker binaries installed inside Ubuntu on WSL?

Comment: Probably! I'm not a Windows users, but Docker only runs on Linux, and historically on Windows or MacOS it runs inside a Linux virtual machine. I don't know if WSL has changed that at all.

Comment: @larsks, so here's what I found, I have docker-desktop specific disto (powershell) : `wsl -v -l` gives `Ubuntu, docker-desktop-data, docker-desktop`. Then when I logged into `docker-desktop` distro through: `wsl -d docker-desktop`, I end up in shell like env where I can run `$ ps uax` and I can see my process id in the table. The parent process id shows the following `/usr/bin/containerd-shim-runc-v2 -namespace moby -id a3d36410d18330e392aa5ad2e72d5048c0d952ffa4bb8ea2b36364e2495942f5 -address /var/run/desktop-containerd/containerd.sock`, where `moby -id container_id_i_see_in_ubuntu`